# Log Analytics data export to storage account- All tables

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I want to use Azure Log Analytics with the data export feature to export all log tables to a storage account.  There used to be an '--export-all-tables' option, but annoyingly this has been removed.

Is there a way I can export all tables?  Not just the ones that exist at the moment, but any future ones that may be created?

Azure Policy?
Azure Functions?
Azure Logic App?

Answer (score 0):

We can archive the data with the help of Logic App, as we run a query from a logic app and uses its output in other actions in the workflow. So here Azure Blob Storage connector is used to send query output to blob storage.

[image]

Here we just need Log Analytics Workspace and Storage account access to achieve this.

And to add on all the new data, we can create a trigger in logic app where we can run it once in a day according to our requirement.

[image]

After setting up the trigger “Click + New step to add an action that runs after the recurrence action. Under Choose an action, type azure monitor and then select Azure Monitor Logs.”

Later after configuring the whole workflow create blob and attach it to workflow as below:

[image]

Later we can run the logic app and check the storage for the logs.

Check for the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-export-logic-app) to understand more about Archive data from Log Analytics workspace to Azure storage using Logic App